# Play Store updates/installs app using a different account than the one the user made IAP through

Tags: google-play, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, in-app-billing

On [this bug report on Github](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/issues/2#issuecomment-305380836) we were asked to raise the issue here.

The issue is quite simple. Sometimes, users have multiple accounts on their phone, let's say `xyz@gmail.com and` abc@gmail.com. They install an app using the account `xyz@gmail.com and make some in-app purchases. Later, when the app is updated, it switches to the other account` abc@gmail.com and the user loses their previous purchases. This is a common issue that occurs frequently with staged rollouts.

The main issue is that users cannot choose which account to use for buying or checking purchases.

The second issue is related to the Play Store app on Android, which fails to recognize the user account selected by the user. The only available workaround to this issue is to make use of the Play Store website, as explained in the workaround mentioned in [this link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/issues/2#issuecomment-259108286) of the same bug report.

It is hard to say what the ideal solution is, but this is indeed a major inconvenience for developers, often resulting in numerous 1-star reviews after each update.

Edit: As pointed out in a comment, I am referring to multiple Google accounts for a single Android user, not multiple Android users within the same phone.

Comment: Great summary of the issue(s). Just to add a point of clarification: the issue has nothing to do with using different accounts with the multi-user feature on devices but rather signing into multiple Google accounts within the same user. For example, on a phone there usually is only one user (but the user can be signed into multiple Google accounts), while on a tablet, there may be more than one user (where each user could be signed into multiple Google accounts).

Comment: Personally, I think the easiest and most widely useful solution is that the Play Store should report purchases from *all* Google accounts for the current user that are signed in on the device.

Comment: It would also be nice if the purchase flow allowed the user to choose which account they want to make a purchase with, but this is an enhancement that I believe is independent of solving this problem.

Comment: @ashughes as I mentioned on Github issue, I'm already addressing this internally and will update here when I have some feedback. Thanks

Comment: @casolorz this feature is under development, but unfortunately I don't have an ETA to share. When it's ready, I'll update this question.

Comment: If a device officially supports multiple, concurrent accounts, then I think the vendor should present the option to the user (or confirm with them) that this is going to be installed against account xyz vs. abc... or the vendor (Google) needs to help resolve this after the fact. That said, this sounds like a slippery slope to piracy/bending the rules... so I can see their hesitation... if not designed and executed really well.

Comment: As an Android user for years and one with 3 google accounts currently across two devices, I don't have this problem anymore and haven't in years.  I've been using Android over 10 years, and it's been easily 5+ since I've seen this.  If I choose the correct account that I purchased something with, I can download it on either phone for free.  This even works if I sign into an app with one account and then purchase something with my only play store account that has a payment method tied to it.  I'm not sure what the cause of your issues are, but it doesn't seem to be Android anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some potential solutions:

1. User Education: Provide clear instructions within the app or on your website on how users can manage their accounts and purchases.
2. Prompt for Account Confirmation: Prompt users to confirm their Google account before making an IAP.
3. Advocate for Improvements: Advocate for changes on the Google Play Store's end regarding how it handles account switching during app updates and IAP.
4. Consider Offering Cross-Account Purchase Restoration: Explore the possibility of allowing users to restore previous purchases across accounts.

Comment: Wouldn't #4 avoid Google's IAP? You would have to have a way to link both accounts, correct?

Comment: #2 - it would be great if Google allowed that but they don't share the account with us developers and the library has no way of selecting an account.